# XML XPath - Sub path

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

Using the following XML, in SQL Server how can I get a table of LineItemId,PetId(value),vetid(Value)? I'm stumped.

Basically, It should return:

```
255fa32c-dce6-4e7a-83a5-4b45f22f00fc   75866   12916
183dc279-53a6-45fc-9e75-57770582b6bc   34535   34546
```

From this XML:

```
<PurchaseOrder>
  <OrderForms>
    <OrderForm>
      <LineItems>
        <LineItem LineItemId="255fa32c-dce6-4e7a-83a5-4b45f22f00fc">
          <WeaklyTypedProperties>
            <WeaklyTypedProperty Name="petId" Value="75866" Type="String" />
            <WeaklyTypedProperty Name="vetId" Value="12916" Type="String" />
          </WeaklyTypedProperties>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem LineItemId="183dc279-53a6-45fc-9e75-57770582b6bc">
          <WeaklyTypedProperties>
            <WeaklyTypedProperty Name="petId" Value="345345" Type="String" />
            <WeaklyTypedProperty Name="vetId" Value="345346" Type="String" />
          </WeaklyTypedProperties>
        </LineItem>
      </LineItems>
    </OrderForm>
  </OrderForms>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

I should state I have tried the following, but it gives blanks for petId and vetId:

```
SELECT 
   p.value('@LineItemId','NVARCHAR(100)')
  ,p.query('//PurchaseOrder/OrderForms/OrderForm[1]/LineItems/LineItem[1]/WeaklyTypedProperties/WeaklyTypedProperty[Name="petId"]')
  ,p.query('//PurchaseOrder/OrderForms/OrderForm[1]/LineItems/LineItem[1]/WeaklyTypedProperties/WeaklyTypedProperty[Name="vetid"]')
FROM 
  dbo.[PurchaseOrdersMarshalledData] pomd 
  CROSS APPLY pomd.[MarshalledData].nodes('//PurchaseOrder/OrderForms/OrderForm[1]/LineItems/LineItem') x(p)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the @ for Name given it's an attribute?

Comment: I dont know SQL Server, but plain XPath 2.0 it could be something like `//LineItem/concat(@LineItemId, ' ', string-join(.//WeaklyTypedProperty/@Value, ' '))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    [LineItemId] = l.value('@LineItemId', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    [PetId] = w.value('WeaklyTypedProperty[@Name="petId"][1]/@Value', 'int'),
    [VetId] = w.value('WeaklyTypedProperty[@Name="vetId"][1]/@Value', 'int')
FROM dbo.[PurchaseOrdersMarshalledData] pomp
CROSS APPLY pomp.[MarshalledData].nodes('//PurchaseOrder/OrderForms/OrderForm[1]/LineItems/LineItem') LineItem(l)
CROSS APPLY l.nodes('WeaklyTypedProperties') WeaklyTypedProperty(w)
```

Comment: You rock. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it... maybe the syntaxis is not 100% correct...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/PurcharseOrder/OrderForms/OrderForm/LineItems/LineItem"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@LineItemId"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="WeaklyTypedProperties"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="WeaklyTypedProperty/@Value"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Can't you shorten `//PurcharseOrder/OrderForms/OrderForm/LineItems/LineItem` into `//LineItem`?

Comment: I thought you want XSLT, haven't read the SQL-Server part. I leave the XSLT template just in case it gives you some hint!

Comment: I think is more correct to access from the root node, just in case you have LineItem nodes in other parts of the XML document (and you don't want to process them)